# Has anyone used OpenAM/OpenDJ/OpenIDM suite without using ForgeRock's Support plans?

Tags: openam, opendj, openidm

We are looking to implement an open source identity management system and have identified ForgeRock's stack as the best technology to implement.

The high cost of ForgeRock support and its per-User pricing model, however, is a potential roadblock. Our current User base is ~45K, but we expect to ramp up to 1M in the next 2 years.

So we're looking into scenarios where we proceed without FR Support. The lack of FR Maintenance releases would seem to put a damper on that, so we're curious if others have gone that route.

1. What has been your experience?
2. What kind of projects have you done this for? Size, etc.
3. In the absence of FR's Maintenance releases, have you been able to easily create your own patches?
4. What are some potential pitfalls?

If there are blogs or other communities that deal with this topic, please point me in their general direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a community user I did use OpenAM(/OpenSSO) and OpenDJ for the past 6 years or so, but it was a very small deployment (10k users only 1 server instance from both products).

1) In the early stages we did have reliability issues with OpenAM, which we mostly resolved by restarting the server instances - clearly wasn't preferred, but we didn't really spend too much development effort on actually trying to resolve it (plus lacked the necessary knowledge for investigation back then). After spending some actual effort on trying to learn the product it turned out that the most of our issues were either self-inflicted (badly written customizations, or misconfigurations), or was actually something that got recently resolved in the OpenAM project and was relatively simple to backport to our version.

Of course the experience itself largely depends on how often you want to make configuration changes in the deployment though, since we weren't changing a lot of things over the years, OpenAM just worked nicely for long intervals without requiring any kind of maintenance.

3) Since we didn't really ran into new issues (the config barely changed), there weren't too many surprises after a while. The security patches were mostly simple to backport and didn't cause too much trouble (It did help that after 1,5 years I became a FR employee and I actively worked on OpenAM issues though :) )

4) I think running without subscription has its risks, but they mostly relate to:

- are you planning to roll out new features based on OpenAM functionality during that 2 years (i.e. are you planning to constantly make changes to the deployment)?
- do you have *good* developers to work on these features? Working with OpenAM for example can quite easily require you to have a look at the source code to figure out how things work, the quality of the documentation has improved a lot over the years though. Regardless, backporting fixes are going to be more and more difficult over time, as the releases will differ a lot more (since the development team is getting bigger and bigger for each projects) - and even then you can't just assume that all the issues you run into are by definition already resolved in trunk. The need to resolve some of the issues on your own is a cost/risk you need to take into account.
- what kind of SLA do you want to have for your deployment? Is your business going bankrupt after a 1 minute outage? Is it acceptable to just frequently restart your service (in case you run into some weird issues)?
- do you really need support for all 3 products? For example my background would allow me to work easily without OpenAM support, but I would be in the deep end if something is going wrong with my provisioning system...

And a generic remark:

Having user growth of 20x within two years sounds a bit unrealistic, or very hopeful at least. Maybe what you should look for is a 1 year subscription for a bit more reasonable target number and then have a renewal once you have a better understanding of customer growth in your business?

Comment: Peter, thanks for all the info. To answer your generic question, the 20x growth would come from incorporating legacy applications with established user bases in the coming years. 

It's good to hear that your experience with the ForgeRock stack has been positive. I'm the primary investigator, so outside confirmation is nice.

We are currently exploring alternate Support pricing models. 

It seems as if the majority of development is happening inside the FR walls. Now that you're inside said walls, is that your experience as well? Are you aware of any "community" versions of their products?

Comment: It's a bit of both worlds: the main development is happening in trunk and public branches, but the actual agile stories are kept private (so you can see what new development goes in, but can't see what use-case it was originally meant to resolve) - this is mostly true for AM, less true for IDM and probably not at all true for DJ/IG. All the bugfixes are going into trunk regardless of product. Haven't heard of maintained community editions yet I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm new to the open source world, so bear with me for one (ok, two) more question(s).

When you say that dev is going on in trunk + public branches, does that mean that non-ForgeRock people can make changes that get incorporated into the trunk? If so, how common is that?

Thanks again.